# Powershell - Idle Timer withForce Logoff

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to create a powershell script that will check the idle time of the currently logged in user and to reboot the machine if it has reached over 30 minutes idle time. I received this code from a co-worker to continue the project. But when I run the code, all it does is immediately reboot the machine. It does not seem to follow the idle timer.

````
    Function Get-IdleTime 
    {
    Add-Type @'
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    
    namespace PInvoke.Win32 
        {
    
        public static class UserInput 
            {
    
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=false)]
            private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);
    
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            private struct LASTINPUTINFO {
                public uint cbSize;
                public int dwTime;
            }
    
            public static DateTime LastInput {
                get {
                    DateTime bootTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-Environment.TickCount);
                    DateTime lastInput = bootTime.AddMilliseconds(LastInputTicks);
                    return lastInput;
                }
            }
    
            public static TimeSpan IdleTime {
                get {
                    return DateTime.Now.Subtract(LastInput);
                }
            }
    
            public static int LastInputTicks {
                get {
                    LASTINPUTINFO lii = new LASTINPUTINFO();
                    lii.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));
                    GetLastInputInfo(ref lii);
                    return lii.dwTime;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    '@
            $Output = @{
            'LastInput' = [PInvoke.Win32.UserInput]::LastInput;
            'IdleTime'  = [PInvoke.Win32.UserInput]::IdleTime
        }
    
        #Store lastInput and idleTime in a property to return
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Output
    }
    
    Function AutomaticReboot {
        #Query Idle Time Using Win32.UserInput GetLastInputInfo
        $idle = Get-IdleTime
    
        #Get idle time, convert to minutes, round to 3 places
        $test = [Math]::Round($idle.IdleTime.TotalMinutes,3)
    
        #Get current logged on user
        $CurrentUser = Get-WmiObject ComputerName -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select UserName
        $CurrentUser = $CurrentUser.UserName
    
        #If idle duration >= defined idle time [30] then write eventlog and perform logout
        If($test -ge $logout){
       
            #Write Event to Application Log, Source Script, EventID 1
            $msg = "Autologout scheduled task triggered for $CurrentUser with an idle time of $test minutes."
            Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source Script -EventID 1 -EntryType Information -Message $msg
       
            #Restart using powershell native command.
            Restart-Computer
        }
        Else{
            #Debug
            $msg = "Autologout script ran for $CurrentUser but idle time of $logout was not met. Idle time at run was $test minutes."
            Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source Script -EventID 2 -EntryType Information -Message $msg
        }
    
    }```
````

Comment: Well, from the looks of it, you're running `AutomaticReboot` which calls `Get-IdleTime`.  If that's the case, where is `$logout` being defined? If that variable is null, or simply not defined, your `if()` condition of `$test -ge $logout` will always evaluate to `$true` leading to the `Restart-Computer`; since `$test` will more than likely always have an idle time regardless if its a split second.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala
Thank you for the response! I asked that question myself while I was reviewing the code, but wasn't sure if it needed to be defined. Since this is measured in minutes, should it be something like $logout = 30m?

Comment: That is correct! You can add that as a parameter as well: `Function AutomaticReboot ($logout = 30) { ... }` in case you would like to switch the timer on it later on.

Comment: @abrahamzinala
So I added in the variable to define $logout and while the script did not crash, it did not reboot 30 minutes later either. In fact, the test machine was left over night and there was no reboot performed.

Comment: Another thing I just spotted in this code that Im not sure about is this.

```        $CurrentUser = Get-WmiObject ComputerName -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select UserName
        $CurrentUser = $CurrentUser.UserName```

Does this not confuse the system using two different definitions for $CurrentUser?

Comment: Depends how you're running the script, is it just constantly running in the background? The code you mention shouldn't affect it. Just assigns only the value to the variable. So, you wouldn't need the 2nd assignment/variable if you use `... | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "UserName"` instead, or just: `(Get-WmiObject ComputerName -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName`.

Comment: @abrahamzinala

Thanks for the assistance again! I've modified the code to only one variable, the (Get-WmiObject ComputerName -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName that you provided. I'll be testing this immediately!


The code is meant to run every 30 minutes, piggybacking on another PowerShell script that's already running like that.

Also, I've used "30" for the $logout variable so far. But I'm wondering if it needs to be something else other than the number. Im wondering this because of this part of the code `$timer = [Math]::Round($idle.IdleTime.TotalMinutes,3)`

Comment: I can't help but feel the reason it's not working is because of how it's being ran. Your `$timer` (*or `$test` variable as shown above*) should work fine since it's returning a type of `[double]`. You can try just `$test = $idle.IdleTime.Minutes` and compare that in your `if()` statement instead.

Comment: @abrahamzinala

Yea, unfortunately what this is going to run on is a very locked down windows system. So I have to find ways around the lockouts. 

I didn't realize the "IdleTime" Innate Function in Powershell was a thing, so I've removed the entire Idle timer I created. Now the code looks like this: `Function AutomaticReboot {
$idle = IdleTime
$timer = "00:00:30.0000000"
If($idle -ge $timer){Restart-Computer}
}`

I am still currently testing this particular code out but I think this should work?

Comment: It's not, the person who wrote this code used a method called "PInvoke" (Platform Invoke) where they use another language code to tap into the Windows API retrieving the idleTime. So, it would be: `$idle = (Get-IdleTime).IdleTime.Minutes; $time = 30; if ($idle -ge $time) { Restart-Computer }`. If that makes sense.